# fabs(-1.#IND000000000000) return -1.#IND000000000000?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nan

EDIT: to reproduce it, use this piece of code.

```
union
{
    double d;
    size_t s;
} d;

d.s = 0xfff8000000000000;
d.d = fabs(d.d);
std::cout << d.d << std::endl;
```

the output is

```
-1.#IND
```

EDIT:  I do not agree this duplicated the other question, sqrt and abs are absolute different functions.  When you send an negative value to sqrt, it may give you -Nan, but for abs, it should give you Nan.

I am using VS2013.  A calculation function return -1.#IND000000000000 (hex 0xfff8000000000000)
, which should mean -Nan in Visual studio and I use fabs() to get it's abs value, it still give me -1.#IND000000000000. I try use std::abs and get same result.

```
double x = some_function(...); // return -1.#IND000000000000
x = fabs(x);
// or
x = std::abs(x);
```

In http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs it only mentioned fabs(-INF)=INF, nothing about NAN or IND.  Is this a undefined behavior, or a bug in visual studio 2013?

Comment: -Nan, why vote down?

Comment: I am sorry but if you are not clear, can you wait someone knows about it to answer?

Comment: There's no such thing as -NaN. It's the same thing as NaN. Unless, of course, you have `-ffast-math` enabled; then all sorts of things get thrown out. Trying to do mathematical things on something that is quite literally **N**ot **a** **N**umber won't get you expected results.

Comment: I am not sure how this value comes, it's from external library method, and in visual studio debug it shows as -1.#IND000000000000.  1.#IND000000000000 is Nan, then that one must be -Nan.  I am not using -ffast-math option, but not sure if the library enabled it.

Comment: No, it's not -NaN. It's just NaN. There are several representations, some of which may happen to look like the negative version of another, but they're all identical under IEEE standards and treated the same way by math libraries -- that is, unpredictably and weirdly.

Comment: It's still confusing.  The NaN value in VS is 0x7ff8000000000000, who highest bit is unset for positive value.  0xfff800000000000 is a negative value for sure.

Comment: "IND" is just how Visual Studio displays NaN. 0xfff800000000000 is NOT a negative value; NaN is neither positive nor negative. There are many bit patterns which are NaN, and some of them have a 1 in the sign bit. That does NOT indicate that they are in any way negative.

Comment: Again, there are multiple representations of NaN. They're all identical, in terms of what they do and how they're treated; the fact that some bits are different is irrelevant.

Comment: I can accept this explanation.  But this disobey math ruler somehow, fabs(x) >= 0 is false in this case.  I have to check is not Nan, then use fabs, otherwise all following calculations are wrong.

Comment: @TigerHwang No, it's perfectly compliant with the relevant standards. Note that `fabs(x) >= 0` is false, but `fabs(x) <= 0` is *also* false. That's what happens when you operate on NaN: you get NaN results. It's definitely a good idea to check for NaNs when you think they might be produced, though it's much better to not produce them in the first place.

Comment: The cppreference page you linked says what happens if the argument is NaN

Comment: I debug into fabs() disassembly, it silently set errno to 33, which means EDOM: Domain error.  This is the first time I know that such function has a limitation in input value.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I guess the person who did did so because of the question and title missing structure (not sure how it looked originally, but now e.g. it's confusing that the question comes right at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching in internet, I get these conclusion:

IEEE-754 defined NAN, the high bit can be signed or unsigned.  It does not define -NAN.

Microsoft defined both NAN and -NAN.

By cppreference.com, fabs function:  If the argument is NaN, NaN is returned.

By MSDN, fabs returns the absolute value of its argument. There is no error return.  But when input is ±QNAN or IND, Matherr Exception is set to _DOMAIN.

Thank you all, @QPaysTaxes, @Sneftel, @Cubbi.

The guy who post some comment and downvote then delete the comment, you behaviour like treating anything you do not understand as bad, and treating youself as know-all.